# TypeError when using ValueError()

Tags: python, typeerror

In the code below, I get the following error:

```
except ValueError():
TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed
```

Code:

```
    numPizza = int(input("Enter the number of pizzas wanted (max 5)"))
    orderPizza = 0
    global order
    order = []
    total_cost = 0

    while orderPizza < numPizza:
        Order_Menu() 
        select_pizza = 0
        good_input = True
        while good_input:
            global selection
            selection = int(input("Enter your selection for pizza(s) 0-12: "))
            try:
                if selection < 0 or selection > 12:
                    print("Not a valid option restarting in 3 seconds")
                    time.sleep(3)
                    continue
            except ValueError():
                print("not a number")
```

Comment: I think you should use `except ValueError:` without the `()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take out the parens from that except

```
try:
   #do something
except ValueError:
   print "doh!"
```